# How can put the values back to the spreadsheet, matching the col headers with the object keys using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can grab the values from a defined range and build an `object` - thanks to this [awesome resource](https://pulse.appsscript.info/p/2022/03/converting-google-sheets-cell-values-to-an-object-array-with-heading-keys-using-google-apps-script/#comment-128). However, the second part is not really clear to me, as the resulting `object keys`, being embraced in `'` makes it behave like a string instead of a `key`?

This is the code used to get the range's values as an object:

```
function savePoEntry2() {
  let data = [
    ["F. Factura\nInvoice Date", "Vence\nExpires on", "# Factura\nInvoice #", "T. Parcial\nSubtotal", "IVA\n%", "IVA\n$", "RTE FTE\n", "TOTAL PESOS\n", "", "TRM\n", "USD\n", "Diferencia\nVariance"],
    ["2022-10-18T05:00:00.000Z", "2022-10-18T05:00:00.000Z", 1547, 10000000, 0.15, 1500000, 200, 11499800, "", 4500, 2555.511111111111, ""]
  ];

  const [headers, ...rows] = data;
  const res = rows.map((r) =>
    headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, {
      [h]: r[j]
    }), {})
  );
  console.log(Object.values(res));
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function savePoEntry2() {
  let data = [
    ["F. Factura\nInvoice Date", "Vence\nExpires on", "# Factura\nInvoice #", "T. Parcial\nSubtotal", "IVA\n%", "IVA\n$", "RTE FTE\n", "TOTAL PESOS\n", "", "TRM\n", "USD\n", "Diferencia\nVariance"],
    ["2022-10-18T05:00:00.000Z", "2022-10-18T05:00:00.000Z", 1547, 10000000, 0.15, 1500000, 200, 11499800, "", 4500, 2555.511111111111, ""]
  ];
  //const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//test
  //const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//test
  //const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();//test
  const [headers, ...rows] = data;
  const res = rows.map((r) => headers.reduce((a, h, j) => Object.assign(a, { [h]: r[j] }), {}));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  let o = res.map(r => { 
    let row = []
    headers.forEach(h =>  row.push(r[h]) )
    return row;
    });
    o.unshift(headers)
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));//You can use o with setValues();
}
```

Comment: That was fast! Thank you!